# Storing values in temp variables and use them in scatter plot - d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a csv data set which has "Position" with xyz co ordinates and subsequent "events" which have different data.("Events" do not have co ordinate data, so I should use the X1 value of "Position" as reference and plot "event" for that Y value) I plot "Time" in X-axis and co-ordinates in Y axis. Below is the sample data:

```
type,studentId,Time,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3
Position,1,92.2,881.42,371.92,1.05,15.93,0,10.4,1
Position,1,93.4,925,416.94,1.05,16.43,0,354.27,1
Event2,1,102.41,4,XXX,hello thank you.
Event3,1,114.4,YYY,Started
Event4,1,120.21,6,XXX,what do u want
Position,1,120.6,930,460.94,1.05,6.58,0,352.9,1
Event5,2,130.4,Random
```

So when I try to store the value in temp variable, the last value of position gets stored as reference (i.e 460.94) But for event2, my X1 should be 416.94
and for event5, 460.9.

I parse the data using "d3.csv"`

```
d3.csv("samp.csv", function(error, data) {


  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Time = +d.Time;
    d.x1 = +d.x1;
//    console.log(d);
  });`
```

And store the x value of position as

```
var temp;
var yValue = function(d) { 

if (d.type == "Position")
{
temp = d.x1;
return d.x1}
else if(d.type=="Event2")
{

  return temp;
}

if (d.type == "Event1")
{
return d.z1}
},
```

Comment: That's not a CSV data set. Well, it seems unlikely it is. Where are the commas?

Comment: My bad, data was initially in notepad, converted it to excel. I have copied it correctly now(edited the post).